# Check for duplicates in a shopping cart and updating the quantity (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, cart, react-functional-component

I have a shopping cart that is a nested list. I want to check if a certain item is already in the list before adding it again. If it is already in the list I just want to update the quantity. What am I doing wrong here, and how can I implement localstorage here (hypothetically)

Here is the function:

```
   function addToCart(e) {
    var updatedCart = [];
    if (cart.includes(e.target.innerText)) {
    console.log("Duplicate found");
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        if (cart[i][0] == e.target.innerText) {
        cart[i][1]++;
        updatedCart.push(cart[i]);
        i++;
        } else {
        i++;
        }
    }
    } else {
    setCart((cart) => [...cart, [e.target.innerText, 1]]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion, it is better (time-complexity wise) to store something like your cart in a javascript object or a map. You could store your item names (it would be better to have some sort of unique id) as the keys, and the item amount as the value; so basically something like that:

```
const cart = {
  itemA: 1,
  itemB: 2,
  itemC: 4
}
```

That way you could just update the value by copying the old state and overwrite only the value of the searched key if it exists

```
const cartCopy = {...cart};
if (!cartCopy[itemName]) {
  cartCopy[itemName] = 1;
} else {
  cartCopy[itemName] += 1;
}
setState(cartCopy);
```

You should improve that code by yourself and using this snippet just as some quick tip, as to use localStorage it would be not that hard. Especially with this object way of doing that; just remind that localStorage is slow to access, so I would suggest to update your component's state first, and when is updated just add into the localStorage your object with some kind of label. You should use localStorage only to have some kind of persistency of your cart through the sessions, so basically you'll load the state from localStorage only when you mount the app (if the cart is always visible) and update the localStorage when there is some update to the local state of your cart.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you very much. Happy New Year in advance.

Comment: @Advait : as long as you've accepted this answer (to the question which wasn't actually asked :), you should bear in mind that using suggested approach is a bad idea (for two reasons at least): one may have products with the same name at a different price (which you wouldn't be able to implement this way, since object keys must be unique); product names can be long enough (too long to be an appropriate object key).

Comment: @Advait : If you consider your data model re-design, you'd be much better off having your `cart` as array of objects, where each item would represent chosen item with all the necessary properties along with unique `id`, e.g. `cart = [{id:1, name: 'apple', cost: 10..`. It is much better scalable, even if above shortcomings are not the case for you ***yet***.

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov yeah, I though of this aswell. Thanks. I just have one question. How do I remove something from my cart Object? I tried delete[item]; but that doesnt seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: @Advait: first off, I would recommend to make up your mind about the method you further proceed with (since, now it's not mine, I may not recommend relevant solution). Second, you may need to post that as a separate question (not to confuse future readers with multiple topics). So, once you do so, I may have a look into that too.

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov ah ok. I have posted it as a question of its own. Thank you. Happy new year in advance.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov As I stated in the answer, I've just wrote down an easy implementation based on his use case. That's a draft and he should improve the solution to meet his requirements. This is why I suggested to use item ids as the keys in the object.

Comment: @Alpe89 : I won't argue whether approach you have suggested is an *'improvement'* or not (because, it, obviously, isn't). You didn't solve the very specific problem stated in OP, you didn't even suggested the way to avoid that, what you did instead - created the new one for OP (even though they're not proficient enough to comprehend that).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the line:

```
setCart((cart) => [...cart, [e.target.innerText, 1]]);
```

I may assume, that your `cart` contains array ***of arrays*** where inner arrays have product name and quantity as its first and second items, repsectively.

If I am correct with that assumption, the condition:

```
if (cart.includes(e.target.innerText))
```

Is never met, hence corresponding block never executed.

One more thing I may suggest is to use `textContent` rather then `innerText` (for [performance considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText)).

So, your `addToCart()` function may look something, like:

```
const addToCart = ({target:{textContent:itemName}}) => {
    const cartShallowCopy = [...cart],
            matchingItem = cartShallowCopy.find(([cartItemName]) =>
                cartItemName == itemName)
    matchingItem
        ? matchingItem[1]++
        : cartShallowCopy.push([itemName, 1])
    setCart(cartShallowCopy)
}
```

following is a proof-of-a-concept live-demo:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const App = () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]),
        addToCart = ({target:{textContent:itemName}}) => {
           const cartShallowCopy = [...cart],
                 matchingItem = cartShallowCopy.find(([cartItemName]) =>
                     cartItemName == itemName)
           matchingItem
             ? matchingItem[1]++
             : cartShallowCopy.push([itemName, 1])
           setCart(cartShallowCopy)
        }
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>These are products:</h4>
      <ul>
        {
          ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'peach'].map(name => (
            <li key={name}>
              <span 
                onClick={addToCart}
                className="productItem"
              >
                {name}
              </span>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
      <h4>This is cart:</h4>
      <ul>
        { !!cart.length && cart.map(([name, qty]) => (
            <li key={name}>{name}, {qty}</li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```css
.productItem:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: purple;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take this into consideration. Happy New Year in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Or basically, just use a `Map`. Helps in performance optimisations as well.
Your cart structure would be like this:

```
{
  productId1:quantity1,
  productId2:quantity2,
  ...
  ..
}
```

A small snippet :

```
      let map = new Map(state.cart);
      let qty = (map.get(id) || 0) + quantity; //if item is not present will just add the item, else update its quantity
      if (qty !== 0) {
        map.set(id, qty);
      } else {
        map.delete(id); //else delete the item from cart
      }
```